# Автоматическое переключение клавиатуры на английский язык и запрет использования других языков кроме английского при нажатии на editText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно задать, чтобы не смотря от ранее используемой раскладки клавиатуры, при нажатии на определённый editText она автоматически переключалась на английский язык, а так же запрет на переключение, для выбранного editText, с английского языка на другие языки.

Comment: Может вот это подойдет? [ссылка на вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484774/android-prevent-other-language-except-english-in-input-with-an-alertdialog)